# easy apns and encoding

Tags: encoding, apple-push-notifications

Using Easy APNS
can i change the encoding of the notification alert after i recieve it on my iphone??

anyway the reason am asking this is because The problem am facing is very strange. i have my messages (string) set in utf8 in sql tables and i can see the correct characters there. the problem is when the message is sent some devices will receive it correctly but other devices will receive strange characters like question marks .. (???????????) !

i have also noticed that when i send the msg and the other device receive it right away then no problem all characters are showing fine! but if the message got queued then received the ???????? will appear !

have any one faced the same problem before? or does any one have an idea whats going on?